# Difficulty to use Laser scanner with URG_NODE

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to get data from a hokuyo laser scanner model (UTM_30LX_EW). I have installed urg_node and all the related dependencies. To check the installation and following the urg_node page in ROS wiki, I run this code:
rosrun hokuyo_node getID /dev/**ttyUSB0**

and I get "Error: package 'hokuyo_node' not found".

I tried to also install the hokuyo_node, but the cat_make failed. I should add my device does not show up on ttyACM0 but on the ttyUSB0. That's why I changed the code accordingly. Although, I guess that will cause some problems as well, so if you know how to make the device to be appeared as ttyACM0 instead of ttyUSB0 please let me know.

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212141/difficulty-to-use-laser-scanner-with-urg_node/) by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try

```
rosrun urg_node getID /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If you have a look at the CMakeLists for the new package(urg_node), it should show you the new names wherever used.

The documentation for urg_node hasn't yet been updated I guess. It is almost still the same as the documentation for the older hokuyo_node package.

For the latter part of the question - I doubt that it really makes much of a difference as long as set it to the right device at initialization.
You might want to have a look at this - ofcourse not on the same package anymore
http://answers.ros.org/question/45850/problem-running-hokuyo_node/

---

Originally posted by [ritwik1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/20200/ritwik1993/) with karma: 36 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1